# Override database option in a user-specific .my.cnf config file

Tags: mariadb, my.cnf

Using MariaDB 10.2.15 (Linux Debian Stretch)

I have created a `~/.my.cnf` config file in my home directory in order to set a default database at connection time for all local client tools:

```
[client]
user=myuser
password=mySecretPassword
database=mydb
```

But I want to unset (skip) option `database` for a specific client program (mysqldump). This is to prevent such warning when running mysqldump:

```
Warning: /usr/bin/mysqldump: ignoring option '--databases' due to
invalid value 'mydb'
```

I was hoping using `skip-OPTIONNAME` in a `[mysqldump]` section would have worked, but unfortunately it doesn't.

```
[client]
user=myuser
password=mySecretPassword
database=mydb

[mysqldump]
skip-database
```

In fact, I noticed that `database` is multi-value. So overriding it is not really possible. For example, the following `.my.cnf` config file:

```
[client]
user=myuser
password=mySecretPassword
database=mydb

[mysqldump]
database=mydb2
```

produces 2 warnings when running mysqldump:

```
Warning: /usr/bin/mysqldump: ignoring option '--databases' due to
invalid value 'mydb'
Warning: /usr/bin/mysqldump: ignoring option '--databases' due to
invalid value 'mydb2'
```

**Is there a way to "unset" option `database` in an overridden section?**

Answer (score 1):

In fact I am realizing that setting `database` option in a `[client]` section is may be nonsense as many client tools won't be compatible.

`mysqldump` and `mysql_upgrade` for example are complaining about this option. So I may specify it in a more specific `[mysql]` section instead:

```
[client]
user=myuser
password=mySecretPassword

[mysql]
database=mydb
```

Even if it meets my needs, It would still be great to find a way to override database option though...